# Ruby .find_all for numbers greater than x

Tags: ruby, findall

I'm new to Ruby and struggling with something that should be very simple.  Use .find_all to return the numbers greater than 10.

Here is what I've tried so far and the response I'm getting:

`nums = [3,9,15,20]`

I get the error message "syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting '}'" when I try the below:

`nums.find_all { |x| x => 10 }`

I can get numbers equal to or even/odd numbers to return when I try, but not greater than or less than.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Complementing the correct answer given by Ursus: The `=>` exists too; if you write a literal Hash, it separates key and value, i.e.`{ "surname" => "Taylor", "given_name" => "Christine" }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Greater than or equal to is `>=` and same, less than or equal to is `<=`

```
nums.find_all { |x| x >= 10 }
 => [15, 20]


nums.find_all { |x| x <= 10 }
 => [3, 9]
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple like that.  Thanks so much!

Comment: My pleasure Christine